# Timing, edits and voting

Tags: discussion, edits, fastest-gun

Sometimes happens that the asker edits the question at the same time as you make an answer.

[Example.](//stackoverflow.com/questions/36914394/saving-file-created-from-browser-to-disk-cannot-use-new-file-on-firefox/36914601#36914601) Difference between question have been edited and the answer have been posted is 20 seconds. And the edit is almost equal to the answer.

Of course, if the question has already contained this point, it would be stupid to post such answer. But if the answer has been prepared and posted - what should be done with it? Should it be deleted? If it's not deleted, should it be downvoted? Remember it was written when the question didn't contain corresponding information.

---

#### More about the example.

My answer is:

> Remove this line
>
> ```
> window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
> ```
>
> Seems like you are disposing url before it is used for download.
>
> Test: https://jsfiddle.net/cLvf7yny/

The question edit is adding of

> Issue seems related to (as if you comment it out works):
>
> ```
> window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
> ```
>
> What is the reasons for this behavior on FF? Should I omit window.URL.revokeObjectURL() at all;

The answer is still relevant, but seems strange...

Comment: If it's no longer valid, feel free to edit or delete it.  Generally, the OP should not make breaking edits, but it's common when the question is new and still being edited/refined.

Comment: If you had posted a good answer it would still be a good answer even after the edit.  You should be including a relevant explanation of what's going on in your answer, for pretty much any question.  Had you done so, the edit wouldn't have meant anything to you.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, the question didn't change.  The OP is still asking about **why** it does not work.

The answer said something about

> Seems like you are disposing url before it is used for download.

But apparently, that didn't help the OP understand why that line was wrong, so it wasn't that high in quality in the first place.